# Tkinter not letting me insert a text in a Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time


schermata = Tk()
screen_width = schermata.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = schermata.winfo_screenheight()
indice = 0
schermata.iconbitmap("immagini\icona.ico")
screen_resolution = str(screen_width)+'x'+str(screen_height)
large_font = ('Verdana',30)
schermata.geometry(screen_resolution)
schermata.title("Jovan's RPG")





class GUI(Frame):

  def __init__(self, master):

        super(GUI, self).__init__(master)

        self.pack()
        self.bg() 
        self.immagine()
        self.testo()
        self.statistiche()
        self.inserimenti()


  def bg(self):

        load = Image.open("immagini\\background.png")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(schermata, image = render)
        img.image = render
        img.pack()

  def immagine(self):           

        load = Image.open("immagini\\dn.png")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(schermata, image = render)
        img.image = render
        img.place( x = 10, y = 10 )

  def testo(self):

        self.testo = Text(schermata, width = 110, height = 35, border = 5, bg = "black", fg ="white")
        self.testo.place( x = 400, y = 20 )

  def statistiche(self):

        self.stats = Text(schermata, width = 40, height = 10, border = 5, bg = "black", fg ="white")
        self.stats.place( x = 10, y = (screen_height - 200))

  def inserisci(self):

        fraseInserita = self.inserimento.get()
        scrivere(fraseInserita)
        self.inserimento.delete('0', END)

  def inserimenti(self):

        self.inserimento = Entry(schermata,font=large_font, width = 25, border = 5, bg = "black", fg ="white")
        self.inserimento.place( x = 400, y = (screen_height - 100))
        self.bottone = Button(schermata, width = 30, height = 3, border = 5, text = "Inserisci", command = self.inserisci)
        self.bottone.place( x = (screen_width - 300), y = (screen_height - 100))

g = GUI(schermata)

def scrivere(scrittura):

      g.testo.insert('1.0', scrittura)

def cancellaTesti():

      g.testo.delete('0',END)

def wait(secondi):

      time.sleep(secondi)
```

Levels class

```
from GUI import *

g = GUI(schermata)

class Livelli():

  def __init__(self): pass

  def cicloLivelli(self):

        self.presentazione()

  def presentazione(self):

        scrivere("Salve avventuriero, qual e' il tuo nome?")
```

Main

```
from GUI import *

a = GUI(schermata)
l = Livelli()

if __name__ == "__main__":

  a.mainloop()
  l.cicloLivelli()
```

As you see i called the function back[(scrivere)], but the interpreter won't let the string appear in the Text widget. I've just posted the class of the GUI and the class of the "levels" that i'm looking forward to use for creating, of course, my levels for the game i'm creating. I'm searching for an answer and can't find it, hope you guys can help.

Comment: where do you initialize root = tkinter.Tk()? Also the last line in main should be root.mainloop()... as I see it a is not an object of tkinter.Tk()

Comment: I've edited the code adding the whole python file, now everything is there

Comment: I've just seen that he gives me this error "in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get something on the screen you need to include `self.config(width=700, heigh=800)` (width and height totally arbitrary :)!) before `self.pack()` in class GUI and change all `schermata` into `self` (as you have defined the instance of GUI as the master frame). 
I made the program put something on screen with the version below and I had to define some variables like `screen_height`, `screen_width` just so to prove the concept. 
I also defined the method `scrivere`. Anyway it is rendering something so hopefully you can proceed. Good luck.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.config(width=700, height=500)
        self.pack()
        # self.bg()
        # self.immagine()
        self.testo()
        self.statistiche()
        self.inserimenti()

    def bg(self):
        load = Image.open("immagini\\background.png")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image = render)
        img.image = render
        img.pack()

    def immagine(self):
        load = Image.open("immagini\\dn.png")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image = render)
        img.image = render
        img.place( x = 10, y = 10 )

    def testo(self):
        self.testo = tk.Text(self, width = 110, height = 35, border = 5, bg = "black", fg ="white")
        self.testo.place( x = 400, y = 20 )

    def statistiche(self):
        screen_height = 400
        self.stats = tk.Text(self, width = 40, height = 10, border = 5, bg = "black", fg ="white")
        self.stats.place( x = 10, y = (screen_height - 200))

    def inserisci(self):
        fraseInserita = self.inserimento.get()
        self.scrivere(fraseInserita)
        self.inserimento.delete('0', 'end')

    def inserimenti(self):
        large_font = ('calibri', 12)
        screen_height = 400
        screen_width = 600
        self.inserimento = tk.Entry(self,font=large_font, width = 25, border = 5, bg = "black", fg ="white")
        self.inserimento.place( x = 400, y = (screen_height - 100))
        self.bottone = tk.Button(self, width = 30, height = 3, border = 5, text = "Inserisci", command = self.inserisci)
        self.bottone.place( x = (screen_width - 300), y = (screen_height - 100))

    def scrivere(self, frase):
        print(' you need to define this function when button is pressed')

class Livelli():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cicloLivelli(self):
        self.presentazione()

    def presentazione(self):
        print("Salve avventuriero, qual e' il tuo nome?")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = GUI()
    l = Livelli()
    l.cicloLivelli()
    a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note you do not need to include the line self.config(width=700, height=500) if you replace the .place(x=, y=) with .pack() or .grid()